# make redirected folders always offline available

Tags: group-policy, folder-redirection, offline-files

I configured server side profiles using GPO (`User Configuration\Policies\Windows-Settings\Folder Redirection`) and that works fine.

**My Setup:**
Redirected Folders reside in `\\servername\Users$\`.
Server is a Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials.
Clients are Windows 10 Professional x64.
The GPO object is linked to the Computers and the Users OU.
In security filtering I added the users group that have folder redirection enabled and the domain computers group.
I also made sure, using rsop.msc, that the computer policies are distributed to the computer that I'm testing this on atm.

My problem is, that those folders aren't cached at all and are sometimes not available during a network hickup or something.

I tried making those folders offline available using GPO but didn't succeed yet. These are the settings I'm trying atm:

In `Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Network\Offline Folders` I have set up:

- Sync all files before logoff: active
- Enable Backgroundsync: active with default values
- Configure slow-link mode: active with "Valuename" set to `\\servername\Users$\*` and "Value" set to "Latency=1"

I hope I translated all of them correctly as I'm on a german server with german GPO.

Is that all that has to be done to enable folder redirection with local caches?

Comment: User Profiles and Redirected Folders are two different things. It's not clear to me which one you're referring to.

Comment: I'm sorry. I redirected AppData, Desktop, Documents, Favorites and Start Menu using the gpo setting quoted in my first sentence.

Comment: (I edited my question and replaced "profile" with "folders" to be more clear what I'm after. Thanks for pointing it out.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess I mixed up roaming user profiles and redirected folders ^^
I set up roaming user profiles now, which is what I aimed for in the first place and deactivated folder redirection.

(That also explains, why I was using "profiles" and "folders" as synonym for each other)

Source that I used to learn the difference: [roaming profile vs folder redirection](https://serverfault.com/questions/465511/roaming-profile-vs-folder-redirection)